# Gray areas on object 2.8

Tags: modeling, mesh

Hey guys Im following up a tutorial from Blender Guru making this anvil. However when i add my sub modifier i get these gray spots. The more i zoom in they get bigger, it doesnt matter how many subdivisions i add in the modifier it stays there, only when i turn sub mod off it dissapears. Its probly a noob problem, i tried googling gray spots but didnt come across anything. 
[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong here (as you can see in the post linked): that's expected for concave subdivided surfaces, and is easily explained. In fact, [blender guru also has the same "artifacts"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuLy9.jpg)

Comment: Ohhh my bad.... It tought hes stuff is some shadow or something. Thanks a lot guys! I started from scratch 2 times... Thanks again!